# can we click the item of listView and add a container Below that item only in flutter

Tags: listview, flutter, flutter-layout

I have a listView,and what i want is whenever i click any item of the listView,just below that item we open a container.
If this cant be done with listView then what can i use to make page like that.

here's the page what im trying to explain u.So, **on click the row with yellow Icon it opened the container below it**

also we can click any row and it should open in only that row.it doesn't matter if we are clicking the 1st,last or middle item of the listView.
if there is any different thing to do this please suggest

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]You can use `ExpansionPanelList` widget or you can use `expandable: ^4.0.1` library

```
class Item {
  Item({
    this.expandedValue,
    this.headerValue,
    this.isExpanded = false,
  });

  String expandedValue;
  String headerValue;
  bool isExpanded;
}

List<Item> generateItems(int numberOfItems) {
  return List.generate(numberOfItems, (int index) {
    return Item(
      headerValue: 'Panel $index',
      expandedValue: 'This is item number $index',
    );
  });
}
List<Item> _data = generateItems(8);
```

and here is a demo for `ExpansionPanelList`

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Container(
      child: _buildPanel(),
    ),
  );
}

Widget _buildPanel() {
  return ExpansionPanelList(
    expansionCallback: (int index, bool isExpanded) {
      setState(() {
        _data[index].isExpanded = !isExpanded;
      });
    },
    children: _data.map<ExpansionPanel>((Item item) {
      return ExpansionPanel(
        headerBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool isExpanded) {
         return Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text('8.11.19'),
            Text('8.11.19'),
            Text('345'),
            Text('390'),
          ],
        );
        },
        body: Container(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text("Paid"),
            Text("390",style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline,),
            RaisedButton(onPressed: (){},child: Text('Yes,Received'),),
            SizedBox(height: 5,),
          ],
        ),
      ),
        isExpanded: item.isExpanded,
      );
    }).toList(),
  );
}
```

i hope it helps..

Comment: In ExpansionPanelList we have to give title,but if u see the design i have given,there i have 2 dates and 2 int value which I'm setting from the ListView.so at the place of title i dont know if i cant set my listView. let me just try it and then ill get back to u

Comment: i am not sure but u can use any widget as title, like rows and colum

Comment: what i did is, i called the listView on title and may be I did something wrong that time,Thanks a lot man for the time and effort u gave @Jaydeep chatrola